# Error invalid use of void expression. Trying to pass a parameter through to the function

Tags: c++, parameters, arduino, void, esp32

I am trying to initialize a server to look as specific inputs based on the request it gets. there are a lot of them so I want to initialize it with a loop as follows:

```
void serverInit() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
        String s = "/readBatt" + i;
        server.on(s, runTest(i));
    }

    server.begin();
    Serial.println("Server started.");
}
```

It's telling me that `server.on(s, runTest(i));` is an invalid use of void expression. I know it wants it formatted as `server.on(s, runTest)` but the function `runTest(int  n)` takes a parameter. How can i pass this parameter through to the function?

Comment: Does `runTest` have a `void` return type?

Comment: If `server.on` is expecting a pointer to a function that does not accept parameters, then your `runtest(int i)` does not meet the required prototype for that function. Provide one that does not accept a pointer, or find the proper function to call with one that does.

Comment: I believe you are correct that it is expecting a function that does not require any parameters. I will have to find a way around this somehow.

Comment: It might be C++, but then `"/readBatt" + i` would be a bug.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @melpomene: It's Arduino - so C++. (Arduino Sketches are compiled using `avr-g++`.) His `String s` is an instance of Arduino's [String](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class.

Comment: @NathanLoucks: Welcome to SO. I suggest you add the 'arduino' tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the [WebServer](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WebServer/src) class from the ESP32 Arduino libraries. As you have gleaned already, the callback specified in the `on()` method does not accept any arguments.

You have an alternative, however. You can specify a 'placeholder' in the URL path - using curly brackets - `{}`. In the callback, then, the corresponding argument can be retrieved by using the `pathArg()` method - which accepts the argument index as parameter.

Example ...

You could define your API endpoint as `/readBatt/<battery number>`. To configure the server to handle requests to this endpoint, then, you would use something like

```cpp
#include <uri/UriBraces.h>
server.on(UriBraces("/readBatt/{}"), runTest);
```

In your callback, you would retrieve the first argument as follows ...

```cpp
static void runTest() {
  String batteryNumber = server.pathArg(0);
  Serial.println("Request to read battery");
  String response = "You attempted to read battery " + batteryNumber;
  response += ".\nThis endpoint is a placeholder. Check again soon!";
  server.send(200, "text/plain", response);
}
```

Finally ... Suppose your ESP8266 was running on local IP address 192.168.1.9. You could access your new API endpoint by opening

> http://192.168.1.9/readBatt/1

in your browser. (Replace `1` with the relevant battery number.)

I don't think there are versions of the `pathArg()` which return an integer, unfortunately, so you may have to perform a conversion at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called a "closure". A closure lets you compose a function which retains access to variables outside of its scope.

A closure is written using a ["lambda expression"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C++_(since_C++11)) - basically an anonymous function. C++'s syntax for lambda expressions looks like this:

```
[capture variable list](argument list) { body}
```

The capture variable list is a list of variables you want to be made available inside the body. The argument list is the normal function argument list that would get passed in by the caller. You'd write the lambda expression you need like this:

```
[i]() { runTest(i); }
```

and use it like this:

```
server.on(s, [i]() { runTest(i); });
```

To be clear, @David Collins' answer is the better way to write the web server. Using a parameter in the URL is better than creating several URLs with the parameter embedded in them. I'm just answering the question of how to pass a parameter to a function that gets called without arguments. If you write the web server code the better way, you won't need to do this (although I would do a bounds check on the value passed in the URL to make sure you're getting a valid battery number).